# Why does jupyter notebook run a cell with a syntax error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In this program is an intentional syntax error

```
import random
random.seed(16)

while True:
    n = random.randrange(1,101)
    print(n)
    if n < 30: break

if n==20:
    break
```

Run with `!python test.py` on google colab yields as expected

```
  File "test.py", line 10
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

But run as a juypter notebook cell on google colab gives the output

```
47
61
62
37
54
30
58
1
  File "<ipython-input-43-35a4321b0145>", line 10
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

In juypter notebook the program runs until leaving the while loop. My understanding was that the cell would be saved in a temporary file and executed using the standard python interpreter. Why is the execution different?

Comment: Put the whole `while` and `if n == 20` part inside an `if True` block. You'll notice how Jupyter breaks up the execution into blocks.

Comment: To me, this seems to me that CPython on the command line works on file basis, while Jupyter does some extra parsing and works on [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) basis.

Comment: @9769953 You are correct. I am wrong. It does not work in Python, Jupyter Lab or Juno. Something fishy.

Comment: I wouldn't call it fishy: it is another way of parsing the code (perhaps undocumented; or perhaps according to the Python standard, parsing is left to the Python implementation). In fact, it may make sense, considering cells in Jupyter are often written as single compound statements (no, not meant as a contradiction).

Comment: It does not work in Jupyter Notebook: Tested (https://jupyter.org/try). Do you know which version of Jupyter Notebook you used?

Comment: The notebook runs on google colab and the script was executed on a standard google colab instance with `!python test.py`.

Comment: Works for me with notebook version 6.1.5, jupyter core 4.6.3, Python 3.9.6. Weird.

Comment: I reproduced it with Google Colab. I believe the answer lies on the implementation. Digging on how Colab works will shine the answer.

Comment: No, because I'm runing the normal notebook, not Colab, and I see the same issue.

Comment: The online notebook at jupyter.org does run a newer version, which pip doesn't want to upgrade to for me. So perhaps it's changed between 6.1 and 6.2.

Comment: I think the answer is still in implementations. It appears that they run top to bottom without evaluating. I just added `goat` to trigger NameError instead of loop, and it run until NameError was triggered

Comment: That is normal behaviour, and also happens when you run a program from the command line. SyntaxErrors are different as they happent a different stage, and apparently for some versions of a Jupyter notebook, the parsing is such that it is split up into (apparently) compound statements, not whole cells.

Comment: Answer is in implementation: One execute the source code directly, which is what you observed while other translate the source code into a more efficient representation and execute this code (which will catch the error).

Comment: Yes, the implementation is different. No, they both parse and then execute code, just in different bunches. There is no "direct source code execution".

Comment: Comments here are suggesting the issue is specific to Google Colab, so you might consider adding the [tag:colab] tag to help attract subject matter experts.